# Dispatch semaphore in UIPreviewAction freezes app

Tags: objective-c, xcode, grand-central-dispatch, 3dtouch

I am using a `UIPreviewAction` with 3D Touch to call a function, which uses a dispatch semaphore for determining when an asynchronous block has finished. But as soon as a dispatch semaphore is involved in those called functions, the UI freezes or rather any user input gets blocked.

How can that problem be solved?

Thanks in advance, Fabian.

---

### Code example:

The UIPreviewAction:

```
UIPreviewAction *action = [UIPreviewAction actionWithTitle:@"Action" style:UIPreviewActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIPreviewAction * _Nonnull action, UIViewController * _Nonnull previewViewController) {
    [(SenderViewController *)self.sender function];
}
```

The function that gets called:

```
- (void)function {

    dispatch_semaphore_t sema2 = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);

    BOOL selected = false;

    UIAlertController *enterPasswordAlert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:alertTitle message:alertMessage preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
    [enterPasswordAlert addAction:[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Cancel" style:UIAlertActionStyleCancel handler:^(UIAlertAction * _Nonnull action) {
        dispatch_semaphore_signal(sema2);
    }]];
    [enterPasswordAlert addAction:[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Action" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction * _Nonnull action) {
        selected = true;
        dispatch_semaphore_signal(sema2);
    }]];
    [self presentViewController:enterPasswordAlert animated:true completion:nil];



    while (dispatch_semaphore_wait(sema2, DISPATCH_TIME_NOW)) {
        [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode beforeDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:10]];
    }

    if (!selected) return;
}
```

Comment: dispatch_semaphore_t freezes app till the time you have not received response. If it still freezes then try to add dispatch_semaphore_signal(sema2); in dispatch_queue_main() .

Comment: That doesn't change anything... the UI is still blocked and I can't interact with the UIAlertController.

Comment: Learn to understand the asynchronous behavior of `UIAlertController`. Use the completion handler and run the code which is supposed to run after `function` returns in the completion handler. In this case it's a misuse of a semaphore.

Comment: Okay, I understand this. But I have another example, where I don't use a UIAlertController but a for-loop, in which several asynchronous methods with completion handler are called, after which other code should be executed when all async methods in the loop are finished.

Comment: Then use a dispatch group rather than semaphores or `NSOperation(Queue)`

Comment: Okay, thank you very much, it works now like a charm! I didn't know about the possibility of using a dispatch group, but that solves my problem.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To close this question I have solved this problem with the solution provided by **vadian**. I simply use a dispatch group and throw my code, which should be executed after a selection has occurred, in the execution block from dispatch_group_notify.